# Intersection problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am given an interval $A=(0,1)$ and $B=(1,2)$. How can I show that $A \cap B$ is an empty set? I tried to prove by contradiction by saying an arbitrary element $k\in A\cap B$ so $k \in A$ and $k \in B$. But I do not know where to go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close! Suppose $A \cap B$ is non-empty. Then we can find some $x \in A \cap B$. This means $x \in A$ and $x \in B$. But this means $x<1$ and $x>1$. A contradiction.